# Вызов пользовательской js-функции через консоль браузера

Tags: javascript, браузер

Есть страница на который выполняется пользовательская javascript-функция через определенный промежуток времени по таймеру после загрузки страницы. Можно ли как-то через консоль браузера вызвать эту функцию, чтобы она выполнилась на странице?

Answer (score 2):

Да, через консоль можно вызвать функцию, но для этого необходимо, чтобы функция была доступна в рамках текущего контекста исполнения. Для примера, алгоритм прост:

1. Ставите точку останова в нужной позиции кода (там где функция будет доступна в рамках текущего контекста)
2. Перезапускаете страницу, и ждете, пока код не остановится в поставленной точке останова
3. Пока код остановлен - можете вызвать пользовательскую функцию через консоль браузера.

Полезные ссылки для ознакомления:

- Основная: [Calling a Javascript Function from Console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9054870/5275890)
- Ну эта так: [run javascript function from browser console “undefined”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22585080/5275890)